# How can I clear the ColdFusion template cache as part of a deployment?

Tags: caching, coldfusion, cfc

I ran into an issue this morning after deploying of some files to a ColdFusion website/application.

I updated an existing CFC with some new code. The CFC has an init() method that returns the instantiated Object:

**Original MyObject.cfc:**

```
<cfscript>
    VARIABLES.MyParam = "";
</cfscript>

<cffunction name="init" returntype="MyObject" output="false">
    <cfargument name="MyParam" type="String" required="true" />

    <cfscript>
        VARIABLES.MyParam = ARGUMENTS.MyParam;

        return THIS;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

**New MyObject.cfc:**

```
<cfscript>
    VARIABLES.MyParam = "";
</cfscript>

<cffunction name="init" returntype="MyObject" output="false">
    <cfargument name="MyParam" type="String" required="true" />

    <cfscript>
        setMyParam(ARGUMENTS.MyParam);

        return THIS;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setMyParam" output="false" returntype="Void">
    <cfargument name="MyParam" type="String" required="true" />

    <cfset VARIABLES.MyParam = Trim(ARGUMENTS.MyParam) />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getMyParam" output="false" returntype="String">
    <cfreturn VARIABLES.MyParam />
</cffunction>
```

Any time an Object that extended this CFC called init(), it was throwing an exception:

> "The value returned from the init function is not of type MyObject."

This issue did not occur in any of the other environments in which this change was deployed - only in Production.

The only thing that fixed it was clearing the template cache in ColdFusion Administrator.

So, I'm either looking for a way to prevent this from happening in the future and/or a way to automatically clear the template cache when I deploy files.

FYI, I currently deploy files using Tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 4):

In your init() (or more preferably, in another reload-style method), programmatically call the Admin API's clearTrustedCache() method:

```
<cfscript>

     // Login is always required (if the administrator password 
     // is enabled in the ColdFusion Administrator). 
     // This example uses two lines of code. 

     adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator");
     adminObj.login("admin");

     // Instantiate the runtime object. 
     myObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.runtime");

     // clear cache 
     myObj.clearTrustedCache();

     // Stop and restart trusted cache. However, only the clearTrustedCache function needs to be called.
     myObj.setCacheProperty("TrustedCache", 0);
     myObj.setCacheProperty("TrustedCache", 1);
</cfscript>
```

This functionality's been in place as far back as CF7 ([Source](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-7-using-administrator.html)). Note that you will need the CF Admin password for this.

I would also recommend clearing the component cache, if you have that option enabled in your admin:

```
    myObj.clearComponentCache();
```

Comment: Note that this will flush the Trusted Cache for the entire server, not just the individual application.  Performance may be a consideration with this solution (or any automated solution).

Comment: You may have better results simply stop/starting the caches rather than actually clearing the cache. I've been finding that clearing the cache with heavy applications particularly with common coldfusion frameworks will hang up an instance instance. Stop/starting seems to have the same effect as without killing the server. Otherwise Shawn's response is exactly what I would suggest.